# Angular Material List disappears with ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Interesting issue. Here's my list code:

```
<md-list flex>  
    <md-list-item class="md-2-line" ng-repeat="device in devices" ng-init="deviceDtl = getDevice(device.$id); tonerCount = tonerCount(device.$id)" ng-click="clickEvent()" >
        <i class="md-avatar mdi mdi-print m-t-5" style="font-size:42px"></i>
        <div class="md-list-item-text">
            <h3>{{deviceDtl.Make}} {{deviceDtl.Model}}</h3>
            <span ng-show="device.create_date" am-time-ago="device.create_date|amFromUnix"></span>
            <span ng-hide="device.create_date">Added date not available</span>
        </div>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

And here's what it produces:

[image]

If I remove the `ng-click="clickEvent()"` from the `md-list-item` then it works:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Agreeing with @Sajeetharan, I'm incredibly confused as to why you even have an `ng-click` attribute if you're not doing anything with it...

Comment: Haha, it was a function, but I changed it to null to match angular materials docs, I'll change it to my function for clarity but yes I am trying to handle a click event. (Also the hover functionality of angular material only works when the ng-click attr is present https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.3/demo/list).

Comment: Can you reproduce that behaviour on a http://codepen.io ?

Answer (score 2):

Stupid mistake, was using

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.css">`

Needed:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.3/angular-material.min.css">`

Comment: You wrote `rel="stylesheet"` two times, it's not necessary. You can write it only one time and it works anyway :)